# Dir function does not find a file, even after copy pasting the path as a parameter

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried to get the Dir() function to work some time now using a rather complicated concatenated string, as seen below:

```
  Dim Path as String

  Path = Dir("PathToSubfolder\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Date)) &  _ 
                             "\Production " & MonthName(Month(Date)) & "*.xlsx")
  MsgBox Path
```

The message box prints nothing (it's just a blank Message Box). After trying to figure out whether I had mistyped the Path somehow, I opened up the correct file, and copypasted its actual Path from options, and subsequently performed: `Path = Dir("PathToSubFolder\2016\June\Production June 2016.xlsx")`, i.e. without any concatenation or anything, simply just the actual filepath and -name. However, Printing `MsgBox Path` returned nothing (NULL) again.

Does anyone have any clue as to why this wont work? I have used Dir quite extensively the last days from the same workbook (albeit not from the same module) without any issues.

Edit: Finally found a workaround. I simply made a variable with the path to the file, `pathtoFile`, and subsequently:

```
Dim pathtoFile As String 
pathtoFile = "C:\Path.to.file\"
Path = Dir(pathtoFile & "*" & MonthName(Month(Date)) & "*")
```

Comment: Does your `pathtosubfolder` include the drive letter or server name?

Comment: @Rory          Yes, the `Pathtosubfolder` has the driver included.

Comment: If you open the workbook in question, then run this from the immediate window, what do you see: `Msgbox Dir(Activeworkbook.Fullname)`

Comment: @Rory          I don't have permission to alter that specfic file. I did however make a copy of the file, and made it macroenabled. Then using `MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Dir(ActiveWorkbook.FullName))` returned what could be expected, i.e. the correct file path and name. This path is not different from the one I try to use in order to open up the particular file from my "original workbook", which seems strange.

Comment: @Rory          Or well, it was a difference. In the new file it was ".xlsm" instead of ".xlsx". The original file I want to open uses ".xlsx" though. Also, from my original workbook I use Dir with the "*" wildcard in the end, so file extensions should not cause any problems.

Comment: You didn't need to alter the file at all, just open it. There must be some difference between the two - perhaps a space here or there.

Answer (score 2):

```
Month(Date)
```

Will return a number, not a name. So you are passing the following argument:

> PathToSubFolder\2016\6\Production 6 2016.xlsx

Which doesn't exist, hence you get a null string returned.

Try

```
Dim Path as String

Path = Dir("PathToSubfolder\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Date)) &  _ 
                             "\Production " & MonthName(Month(Date)) & "*.xlsx")
MsgBox Path
```

the `MonthName()` method takes a number between 1 - 12 and returns the name of that month, which is what you need for your string.

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted the code. It still returns NULL. What I find the most particular is that using the Dir function "hard-coded" still returns NULL. '

Comment: Have you got some kind of custom error handling going on? If the file can't be found the `Dir()` method will return `vbNullString` (i.e. an empty value, displayed as blank) rather than 'NULL'

Comment: Thanks for replying again. It appears that I have been rather vague. I mean that when I use the MsgBox all I see is blank, which I take as NULL. I have not however used any custom error handling.

Comment: Then unfortunately it has to be the case that you're getting the path or the filename wrong in some way. See Rory's comment above (rather than duplicating the discussion in these comments)

Answer (score 0):

if you concatene strings you need to reattribute the value to the variable then it will be considered as a string.
ex.:
dossierannuel = chemingeneral & Year(Date) & ""
dossierannuel = dossierannuel